# Python SQLite JSONSTRINGLIST

Tags: python, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I have converted an XML (NAS) - File into a SQLite-Database using ogr2org - which worked quite well. Now I'd like to read the data using Python (3.72) - which works quite good as well. But there is a datatype (columntype) called JSONSTRINGLIST, which I have never seen before - even google seems not to know it. Can anybody tell me how to convert the data to a Python tuple or list?

Comment: Could you give a link to source data and show your ogr2ogr command?

Answer (score 1):

after some reading and thinking I found the answer on my own:

```
import json
# ...
listOfElements = json.loads(jsonstringlist)
for element in listOfElements:
    print(element)
```

I hope this helps in case someone faces the same problem